# Escape spaces on file paths when running rsync -av `cat /path/to/file` /destination/

Tags: macos, terminal, rsync

I have a plain text file with a list of paths (about 120 of them, one per each line) that I need to rsync into a single directory, for this, I'm using [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766284/read-input-from-a-file-and-sync-accordingly):

```
rsync -av `cat /path/to/file` /destination/
```

The issue is that the paths contain spaces that are escaped with \ so they look like this:

```
/path/to\ some/directory-001/
/path/to\ some/directory-003/
...
/path/to\ some/directory-120/
```

When I run the command above I get:

```
rsync: link_stat "/path/to" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/path/to/some/directory-001/" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

It works perfectly if there are no spaces in the paths. I tried wrapping the paths in double quotes, single quotes, remove the \ with or without quotes.

Please let me know if there is a way around this, I may be missing something on the actual command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use double quotes `"` to use the file/dir with spaces, for example using `xargs`:

```
$ xargs < file -L1 -I {} rsync -av "{}" /destination/
```

In this case, your file with the paths will be passed to `xargs` the one will be read line by line `-L1` and use `{}` as the placeholder for the line.

If you would like to run things in parallel you could also use the option `-P`, for example, if you have 4 cores you could use something like this:

```
$ xargs < file -P4 -L1 -I {} rsync -av "{}" /destination/
```

To show full path on the source you could try something like:

```
$ xargs < file -L1 -I {} sh -c "echo $(pwd -P)/{}; rsync -av {} /destination/"
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you for your help. Now the last thing I need, which may be unrelated to this question, is for rsync to show the full source path, as would like to see in which of the 120  "/directory-00X/" is rsync on, but by default rsync only shows the destination path when using --progress. Any tips on this?

Comment: @RichardPastenes check updated answer probably could give you a hint :-)

Comment: I ended using -t so xargs will show me the current command being run, which contains the pat, using a log file with rsync and ina new window tail -f into it to see the current files being copied:

`xargs -t < paths -L1 -I {} sudo rsync -a  --progress  "{}" /destination > rsync.log`

and 

`tail -f rsync.log`

Thanks a lot for your help @nbari